# Primefaces Chips component does not add item to List

Tags: jsf, primefaces

the Chips component it's not updating List model in managebean Using the  next tutorial [chips u](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/primefaces/chips.html) I am trying to update the model of a p:chips component, I am using Apache tomcat 9, and primefaces 6.2, I've added some data in this List using PostConstruct, the data list is displayed in the component, but when some items are added in the view no items are modified in model manage bean, after see the logger the items.size() remains unchanged, the component behavior in the view reacts as expected. On windows machine it's working as expected.

My xhtml

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cmp="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/cmp">

<h:form id="formChips">
    <p:outputLabel for="items" value="Items: " /><br/>
    <p:chips id="items" value="#{beanChipsViewer.items}" inmediate="true"  >
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{beanChipsViewer.chipsSelect}" update=":itemList chips"/>
        <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" listener="#{beanChipsViewer.chipsDeselect}" update=":itemList chips"/>
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="chips" delay="300" />
        <p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this" update="chips" delay="300" />
        <p:ajax event="click" process="@this" update="chips" delay="300" listener="#{beanChipsViewer.mostrar}" />
        <p:ajax event="mousedown" process="@this" update="chips" delay="300" />
        <p:ajax event="mouseup" process="@this" update="chips" delay="300" />
    </p:chips>
    <br/>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" update=":itemList" action="#{beanChipsViewer.agregar()}"
        actionListener="#{beanChipsViewer.mostrar}"
    />
    <br/>
</h:form>
<br/>

<p:outputPanel id="itemList">
    <p:repeat  value="#{beanChipsViewer.items}" var="item">
        <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
        <br/>
    </p:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>

<h:panelGroup id="chips">
    <h:outputText value="#{beanChipsViewer.items}" />
</h:panelGroup>

<br/>
```

This is the managed bean coded:

```
  @Named
@ViewScoped
public class BeanChipsViewer implements Serializable {

    private String itemSelected;
    private String itemUnselected;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeanChipsViewer.class);


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
            items.add("etiqueta "+i);
    }

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public  void agregar(){
        logger.info("Entra " +items.size());
        items.add("nitro");
        logger.info("zize after intro" +items.size());
        UtilsPrimefaces.executeUpdatePF("itemList");
    }

    public void mostrar(){
        logger.info("Entra mostrar");
        for(String m:items){
            logger.info("chipItem "+ m);
        }
    }

    public void chipsSelect(SelectEvent e){
        logger.info("chip seleted"+e.getObject().toString());
        this.setItemSelected(e.getObject().toString());
        items.add(e.getObject().toString());
        logger.info("items size afteR chipselected "+ items.size());
    }


    public void chipsDeselect(UnselectEvent e){
        logger.info("chip deselect"+e.getObject().toString()+" "+items.size());
        this.setItemUnselected(e.getObject().toString());

    }

    public void phaseListener(PhaseEvent e){
        List<FacesMessage> messages = e.getFacesContext().getMessageList();
        System.out.println(messages.size());
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have inmediate="true" that would skip all validation and binding.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment, without inmediate="true", remains the same behavor, I cannot upgrade the primefaces version, because it's legacy system maintain.

Comment: How can it be maintenance if you are adding new features/functionality? And maintenance is what you regularly do with cars too. Replacing old oil with new, replacing filters... same as replacing old PrimeFaces with new

Comment: okey @Kukeltje  thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1):

I have to use the next imports

```
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
```

I was mixing @ManageBean with CDI